# Who is the walker that Michonne saw in Season 4 Episode 9?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-walking-dead

In the walking dead season 4 episode 10 [*After*](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/After), there is a scene where Michonne gets back to the prison and sees nobody there. Then, she uses her old technique of camouflage and uses two trapped walkers as protection by tying them with ropes and cutting their jaws and arms.

Then several walkers walk with her as she is also a walker, Then she is taken aback by the sight of a specific female walker, as it physically resembles her. After a while she again saw the walker and then she kills all walkers beside her including her pets.

Who is the walker? The hairstyle of the walker and Michonne looks the same, so she could be in any relation. But I didn't find anything to prove it.

Is she really saw her or was that a hallucination? and who is she really?

I didn't watch further episodes.

Comment: it's been a while, but I think that Michonne's reaction there was because she was beginning to imagine herself as a walker (being always surrounded by them.)  There was nothing special about that one walker, other than a passing physical similarity.

Answer (score 1):

Small spoiler ahead: somewhere in the latter episodes she says something like being with walkers was safe because of camouflage but it wasn't life. Being with people is life. She even said that she doesn't love her sword, because it is part of that life among walkers.

She was still restless in prison and constantly going out because she still didn't handle and accept her loss when everything started, but she liked the prison and people trying to live normally. She was broken when prison went down and tried to switch to her old way, but she couldn't accept it again.

The female zombie that resembled her was not a hallucination, but the final trigger. Where she will end up, and who she is at that moment if she just walks among the walkers. It is so striking that she doesn't try to sneak out, but risks her life to fight walkers and decides who she wants to be. So death to walkers, and out to find other survivors, no more camouflage.

Comment: There is a lot of interesting information here, but could you reformat this so it actually reads as an answer to the question?

Comment: @Joachim The (now) third paragraph pretty much sums up the relevance of the walker she saw. And the preceding paragraphs are the necessary build-up for that.